# how to sum array values with if condition

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach

I got the following array from my code.

```
foreach($JobworkMaterialJson as $key => $value) { 
    $decode = json_decode($value->jobcard_jobwork_json); 
}
```

by the print_r($decode), I got following result now I want to sum values which id is same. 
e.g. id=6 qty would be 25. help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

```
<pre>Array(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 9
        [qty] => 5
    )
)
</pre><pre>Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 6
        [qty] => 10
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 7
        [qty] => 5
    )
) 
</pre><pre>Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 6
        [qty] => 15
    )
)
</pre>
```

Comment: how you create this array share that code ?

Comment: If you got this array from a database query if you show the query someone will show you how to do all this as part of the query

Comment: foreach($JobworkMaterialJson as $key => $value) {
                                        $decode = json_decode($value->jobcard_jobwork_json);
                                    }

Comment: You can edit your question to add extra information. If its code you are adding it is better to edit the question as code is unreadable in a comment

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using an associative array (a dictionary) to keep track of the counts. Iterate over all the inputs and update the dictionary.

**Example code**

```
<?php
$items = array(); // this should be the array you refer to in your question.

$dictionary = array();
foreach($items as $item) {
    if(array_key_exists($item->id, $dictionary)) {
        $dictionary[$item->id] += $item->qty;
    } else {
        $dictionary[$item->id] = $item->qty;
    }
}
```

`$dictionary` now contains the sums. For example `$dictionary['6']` will return `25`.

Comment: it contains only $dictionary['6'] => 10